# How to commit only certain revisions to a cloned repository

Tags: mercurial, branch, tortoisehg

We have recently moved from Perforce to Mercurial, and we are struggeling a bit to find out how to merge only certain changes to our stable releases.
We have a central repository that all developers clone from. 
In Perforce, we have been using  branches to maintain releases, and then merging only bug fixes per change lists from branches into trunk, or the other way around into branches that needed that fix.

In Mercurial, we have implemented this by cloning, where each stable release is a cloned repository of trunk.

Our structure looks a bit like this:

```
Trunk
|- Release 1
|- Release 2
|- Release 3
```

My question is, how can we merge only specific change sets from trunk into a branch? I hope there is an easy way to do it, preferably using TortoiseHg, since we have a lot of developers with different experience level that will be doing this.

Comment: I think your repo set-up is working against you. It's much easier to do fixes on releases, and merge back to the development tree, than having fixes on the development tree, mixed in with other stuff, and merge into releases.

Answer (score 1):

I might not understand fully what you want to do.. but yes you can take changes from one **branch** into another **branch** (e.g., from the trunk, called `default` in Mercurial, to a release branch). In modern Mercurials, this can be done using the `graft` command (or before the `transplant` extension). To use it on a branch type: `hg graft REVISION` (see `hg help graft` for more details).

Now what I don't understand is that it seems that you do not have several branches but only one (`default`) and several clones (?), in which case everything becomes a bit more complicated.. You could pull only one changeset but then you need to pull also its ancestors and it is difficult to know what you actually get into your clones working directories! So I would really advice to create the release branches!

Hope it'll help.

Comment: `hg graft` doesn't need to be enabled as it is not an extension.

Comment: `hg transplant` can be used in this instance as it can copy changesets between repositories without having to pull.

Comment: Steve, right, sorry about that. I edited and changed to "command" instead of extension. Whether with `graft` (and `pull`) or with `transplant`, I still think that it is not advisable to do so as it is difficult to keep track of what was done (compared to using branches).

Comment: Yeah, I agree with that statement. It would be a nightmare to keep track of which revisions were in which release.